# What does "the engraved cross marks worn to a mangled circle" mean?

Tags: cinder

In Cinder (by Marissa Meyer) the following passage appears on the first page:

> The screw through Cinder's ankle had rusted, **the engraved cross marks worn to a mangled circle.**

What does the bolded portion mean?

Comment: It sounds like a "poetic" description of a stripped Phillips-head (or cross-head) screw.  https://images.app.goo.gl/z2ChwZtbcLJBqgNu9

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm - I'd upvote that as an answer. Maybe include a pic like this one? https://empire-s3-production.bobvila.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Strippedbolt.jpg

Answer (score 12):

As has been stated in the comments, this is likely a reference to a stripped [Phillips-head screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_F._Phillips) head.

[image: Image showing a lightly marred Phillip's head screw and a badly stripped one]

> The importance of the crosshead screw design lies in its self-centering property, useful on automated production lines that use powered screwdrivers.

Like any screw, if too much pressure is applied (especially if the screw is not made of strong material to start with or the material has been corroded, such as by rust), the edges of the indentation become twisted and compressed, making it more difficult to gain traction on the screwhead, eventually requiring it to be drilled out, removed, and replaced. The implication is both that Cinder has not been able to afford to replace the screws, and that they may have been made out of cheap metal to start with.

As Valorum pointed out, the next paragraph supports the stripped screw supposition:

> Her knuckles ached from forcing the screwdriver into the joint as she struggled to loosen the screw one gritting twist after another. By the time it was extracted far enough for her to wrench free with her prosthetic steel hand, the hairline threads had been stripped clean.

Comment: I have periodically run into screws intentionally built to strip, usually on devices where they want to make it difficult to open it, and obvious if someone has done so, such as on some military hardware where you want to be able to spot tampering, or proprietary electronics where they want to be able to void the warranty for a gaming device that's been opened up (possibly to install an illicit override chip), but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: The next paragraph is "*Her knuckles ached from forcing the screwdriver into the joint as she struggled to loosen the screw one gritting twist after another. By the time it was extracted far enough for her to wrench free with her prosthetic steel hand, the hairline threads had been stripped clean.*"

Comment: @Valorum: that’s rather confusing since the head and threads can strip independently of each other, though the latter is a good way to get the former if it was stripped by being cross threaded or something

Comment: @Shamshiel "hairline threads" paired with high torque suggests that the writer wasn't that familiar with screws.

Comment: @Shamshiel Somebody "skilled in the art" would normally refer to threads stripping and the recess in a head rounding. They'd probably also appreciate that it's usually the female thread that strips, the fact that they don't in this case suggests that it would be generous to "cut them some slack" when it comes to terminology.